# Copy and paste graph of one PowerPoint presentation to another PowerPoint presentation with inputbox

Tags: vba, powerpoint, shapes, inputbox

Hello :) what I want to do is to have a Master document (PowerPoint) to use as template and personalize with graphics that are in another PowerPoint presentation. The master document on the code is "pre". The PowerPoint with the graphics is "graphs_pre". The idea is to click in a image on a slide of "pre" and a input box appears asking "Please enter the name of the graph", we write the name of the graph, the code opens the "graphs_pre" search for the graph with the same name and copy and paste on the "pre". This isn't working, always giving a lot of errors. So I need your help please. Please bare in mind that I have zero experience in coding...

Code:

```
Sub test() 

Dim vSlide As Slide

Dim vSlide As Slides

Dim vShape As Shape

Dim vShapes As Shapes
Dim pre As Presentation 

Dim graphs_pre As Presentation

Set pre = ActivePresentation

Set graphs_pre = Presentations.Open ("path of the graph presentation", msoFalse) 

strResult = InputBox ("Please enter the name of the graph") 

Set vShapes = Presentations(Dir("path of graph presentation").Slides.Shapes

For each vShape in vShapes 
If strResult = vShape.Name Then

vShape.Copy

pre.Slides.Paste

End If 

Next vShape
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Need to understand what errors (error number and error text) you get and on which line(s) of code before could propose fixes ... though certainly the line starting `Set vShapes = ` will not work as the Slides collection does not have a Shapes property

Comment: @JohnM Exactly on that part gives the error "Compile error: Method or data member not found". And if for example in that statement I put at the end Slides(2).Shapes instead of Slides.Shapes, it gives me the error Run-time '-2147188160 (80048240)': Slides (unknown member): invalid request. Clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if this (air code) gets you a little closer:

```
Sub test() 

Dim vSlide As Slide

'Dim vSlide As Slides
Dim vSlides as Slides

Dim vShape As Shape

Dim vShapes As Shapes
Dim pre As Presentation 

Dim graphs_pre As Presentation
' You use this later w/o DIMming it so add this
Dim strResult as String

Set pre = ActivePresentation

Set graphs_pre = Presentations.Open ("path of the graph presentation", msoFalse) 

strResult = InputBox ("Please enter the name of the graph") 

' I don't understand what this is supposed to do
' Set vShapes = Presentations(Dir("path of graph presentation").Slides.Shapes
' but I THINK you need to do this:
For each vSlide in graphs_pre.Slides
For each vShape in vSlide.Shapes
If strResult = vShape.Name Then
vShape.Copy

' This will paste onto the first slide in pre for now
' Which slide do you really WANT it on?
pre.Slides(1)Shapes.Paste

End If 

Next ' vShape
Next ' vSlide
 
End Sub
```

And once you're all done, you'll want to do graphs_pre.Close